# Banner 7 Magento - Problema com o link

Tags: magento, link, slider, slide, flexslider

Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema com o banner rotatório do seguinte site: [http://todabeauty.com.br](https://todabeauty.com.br).

Como podem ver, o segundo slide possui um link clickável na imagem com o texto: "Saiba mais". Mas estou tentando fazer com que a imagem toda do slide seja linkada. De maneira que seja preciso apenas clickar na imagem para ir a página do link em questão. Porém sem sucesso.

Abaixo o código do Banner 7:

```
<?php 
/******************************************************
 * Website: http://www.plazathemes.com
*******************************************************/
?> 
<?php if($this->getConfig('enabled')){ ?>     <!-- start enable -->
    <?php $cur_store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() ?>
    <div class="ma-banner7-container">
        <!--<div class="container">-->
            <div class="flexslider ma-nivoslider">
        <div class="ma-loading"></div>
        <div id="ma-inivoslider" class="slides">

                <?php
                    // Get data banner
                    $slide = $this->getDataBanner7();
                    $path = Mage::getBaseUrl('media');                  
                    $qty_Item = $this->getConfig('qty_item');
                    if ($this->getConfig('auto')) { $auto = 'true'; } else { $auto = 'false'; }
                    /* Get max item & qty item */
                    if ($qty_Item > count($slide)) {
                        $qty_Item = count($slide);
                    }
                ?>
                <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($slide as $s) {
                        if($i <= $qty_Item) {
                            //Get images slide show
                            $st1 = $s['image'];
                            $p1 = strpos($st1,'banner7');
                            $st2 = substr($st1,$p1+7);
                            $p2 = strpos($st2,'"');
                            $imag = substr($st2,0,$p2);
                    ?>
                    <img style="display: none;" src="<?php echo $path.'magentothem/banner7'.$imag;?>" alt="" title="#banner7-caption<?php echo $i; ?>"  />
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php
                        }//end if
                    } // end foreach
                ?>
        </div>
                <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($slide as $s) { ?>

                            <div id="banner7-caption<?php echo $i; ?>" class="banner7-caption nivo-html-caption nivo-caption">
                                <div class="banner7-title">
                                    <h3><?php echo $this->__($s['title']) ?></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="banner7-des">
                                    <?php echo $this->__($s['description']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if( $s['link'] ) { ?>
                                    <div class="banner7-readmore">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $s['link']?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Saiba mais') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Saiba mais') ?></a>   
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>                      
                <?php
                    $i++;
                    }
                ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $jq(window).load(function() {
                $jq('#ma-inivoslider').nivoSlider({
                    effect: '<?php echo $this->getConfig('animation') ?>',
                    slices: 15,
                    boxCols: 8,
                    boxRows: 4,
                    animSpeed: <?php echo $this->getConfig('interval') ?>,
                    pauseTime: <?php echo $this->getConfig('speed') ?>,
                    startSlide: 0,
                    <?php if (!$this->getConfig('nav_ctrl')) { ?>
                    controlNav: false,
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if (!$this->getConfig('next_back')) { ?>
                    directionNav: false,
                    <?php } ?>
                    controlNavThumbs: false,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    manualAdvance: false,
                    prevText: 'Prev',
                    nextText: 'Next',
                    afterLoad: function(){
                        $jq('.ma-loading').css("display","none");
                        //$jq('.banner7-title, .banner7-des, .banner7-readmore').css("left","100px") ;
                        },     
                    beforeChange: function(){ 
                        $jq('.banner7-title, .banner7-des').css("left","-2000px" );
                        $jq('.banner7-readmore').css("left","-2000px"); 
                    }, 
                    afterChange: function(){ 
                        $jq('.banner7-title, .banner7-des, .banner7-readmore').css("left","40px") 
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
<?php } ?> <!-- end enable -->
```

Answer (score 0):

grande Felipe,

podemos observar dois blocos de codigo q iniciam com `foreach`

o primeiro serve para carregar as imagens, usando o codigo:

```
<img style="display: none;" src="<?php echo $path.'magentothem/banner7'.$imag;?>" alt="" title="#banner7-caption<?php echo $i; ?>"  />
```

o segundo serve para exibir o botao "saiba mais".
entao neste primeiro foreach, vc vai alterar a linha acima por:

```
<?php if( $s['link'] ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $s['link']?>">
        <img style="display: none;" src="<?php echo $path.'magentothem/banner7'.$imag;?>" alt="" title="#banner7-caption<?php echo $i; ?>"  />
    </a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <img style="display: none;" src="<?php echo $path.'magentothem/banner7'.$imag;?>" alt="" title="#banner7-caption<?php echo $i; ?>"  />
<?php } ?>
```

nao testei, mas imagino q deve funcionar.. se nao funcionar, vai ser por algum pequeno detalhe a ser revisado.. mas o codigo eh praticamente este ai. :)

sucesso ai.

Comment: Funcionou!

Me confundo muito com PHP.

Muito Obrigado, valeu mesmo!